# Aliasing comp as º and partial as ¬ in clojure

Tags: clojure, conventions

I missed a short syntax to express fundamental operations over functions in Clojure. Because of that, I started to use `º` as a shorthand for `comp` (cause it's closer to the math operator but easily accessible) and `¬` for `partial` (because reminds me of missing parameters).

What are your thoughts about this? is it useful or does it have the risk of making code confusing?

Comment: ¬ is the standard symbol for logical negation -- I'd expect `(¬ f)` to mean `(comp not f)` (if not simply `(not f)` !).

Comment: jum i agree, i'll have to choose another symbol, any suggestions?

Comment: Not really, I'm quite happy with `partial` (and `comp` for that matter). I remember Sean Devlin used `&` for `comp` and `p` for `partial` in an episode of [Full Disclojure](http://vimeo.com/channels/fulldisclojure) -- if you really want to abbreviate the names in your code (as saved on disk -- see my answer for a possible way to decouple what's displayed from what's actually stored), these might be reasonable choices.

Comment: Totally agree with this - single character function names for these functions. In fact, I think Clojure should have a notion of abbreviated names and full names in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer not to use non-ASCII characters in code (outside of string / character literals and comments). How about having your editor prettify the code for you when it's displayed, but not when saving it? E.g. the following function will cause Emacs to display `comp` as `∘` (the actual function composition symbol):

```
(defun pretty-comp ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil `(("\\<\\(comp\\)\\>"
          (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                    (match-end 1)
                                    ?∘)
                    nil))))))
```

Apparently it's not perfect -- it seems to mangle the display of `compfoo` etc. -- but you might be able to tweak it to work for you.

Answer (score 4):

As a rule of thumb, I would be very hesitant to invent new names for already-named established concepts.

Answer (score 3):

It's confusing for people who don't know the notation. I imagine it's probably quite difficult to type, too. I'd just stick with the standard names.

Comment: Sure im a not objective but i think is relativily easy to remember (at least for me) after seeing the definition and perhaps the shorter syntax (near haskell dot operator) worth. We must carefully select the forms to be shortened but i think comp and partial are basic higher order functions and good candidates...
But i get your point.